# Promise {<pending>} situation on my Fetch VueJs/java App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Hola developers in this app im building using java as back , and Vue as front, im struggling  with a little problem :
On my fetch to the end point to retrieve certain data the process goes through promises which eventually as lenght as each one of them get commited the data get extracted in fact. After several verifications on my logs , in the managment state (Vuex), the data got stored and displayed without problems , but when i try to retrieve it from one of the components of the SPA, throws me the status:
Promise {}

Lets say i got my end point and the fetch to its  enclosed in this method:

```
allGames({ commit }) {
      fetch("/crabs/game/all", {
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        method: "GET",
      })
        .then((response) => {=================FIRST PROMISE, REWTURNING THAT DATA CONVERTED TO JSON
           console.log(response);
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((response) => {=====SECOND PROMISE WOULD COMMIT THAT DATA IN A MUTATION TO MODIFY THE STATE
          response
          console.log(response);
          commit("setAllGames", response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {======HANDLING ERROR ON THE FETCH
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

then mutations, state and getters would be like this

```
State

   allGamesData: {},

Mutations

     setAllGames(state, payload) {
      state.allGamesData = payload;
    },
Getters

    getAllGames: (state) => {
       console.log(state.allGamesData;)===verifyiing the data stored in state
      state.allGamesData;
      
    },
```

When i trigger the component , trying to fetch that data :

```
Home View Component

template>
  <v-container >
    <GameComponent ></GameComponent>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>

import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {};
  },

  components: {},
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["allGames"),

   },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getAllGames"]),
    
  },
  created() {
    this.allGames()
    console.log(this.allGames());
  }
};
</script>
```

I just through the created() function initialize that action of getting all the data , in this case accesing the function of Vuex allGames ;but eventually when checking on my logs turns to be this status of Promise Pending

[image]

Not letting me to move forward in the process.Any advice about what i should improve?
Really thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

`allGames` does return a promise. What you are seeing in the console is completely accurate. Try something like this in your created function:

```
created() {
    this.allGames().then(() => // make the request and wait until complete
       console.log(this.getAllGames()); // look at the *getter* to see what is in state
    )
    
}
```

Also, you should just return from the getter, like so:

```
getAllGames: (state) => {
    return state.allGamesData;
},
```

Comment: Keeps throwing me undefined

Comment: @EnriqueGF you may need to `return fetch(...` in your `allGames` action

Comment: Is quite frustrating cause still keeps the same promise pending situation

Comment: @EnriqueGF Are you *certain* that you are calling `console.log(this.getAllGames());` and *not* `console.log(this.allGames());`? Also you are trying to console.log twice. I would recommend simply returning from the getter. I will update my answer